# How to store the output come from cases just store into an object

Tags: scala, dictionary

Whenever i will call getJsonKeyValue it should print the output like below,How can i store the value of getJsonKeyValue and using accordingly.

```
      getJsonKeyValue(WithMap: Map[String, Any])

      def getJsonKeyValue(mapIs: Map[String, Any]) {

         mapIs.foreach {
            case (k: String, v: List[Map[String, Any]]) =>  v.foreach(x => getJsonKeyValue(x))
            case (k: String, v: Any) => (k + "=" + v)

      }

    }
```

mapIs

```
Map(RedDef -> List(Map(RedTypP -> ^.{14}XY.*$, RedTypC -> XY, ExpNoOfAt -> 19, attributes -> List(Map(AttId -> 1, AttNa -> Pro Ty, AttMaxLen -> 1, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 2, AttNa -> Pro Cod, AttMaxLen -> 6, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 3, AttNa -> REQ CODE, AttMaxLen -> 7, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN))), RedLen -> 117, RedDeIn -> 2, MinNoOfAt -> 19), Map(RedTypP -> ^.{14}JK.*$, RedTypC -> JK, ExpNoOfAt -> 10, attributes -> List(Map(AttId -> 1, AttNa -> Log Si Ty, AttMaxLen -> 1, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> A)), Map(AttId -> 2, AttNa -> Log Si Cod, AttMaxLen -> 6, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 3, AttNa -> Ex Qu Cod, AttMaxLen -> 7, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN))), RedDeIn -> 3, MinNoOfAt -> 10), Map(RedTypP -> ^.{14}FK.*$, RedTypC -> FK, ExpNoOfAt -> 33, attributes -> List(Map(AttId -> 1, AttNa -> Pro Ty, AttMaxLen -> 1, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 2, AttNa -> Pro Cod, AttMaxLen -> 6, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 3, AttNa -> REQ CDE, AttMaxLen -> 7, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 4, AttNa -> RED Ty, AttMaxLen -> 2, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN))), RedLen -> 117, RedDeIn -> 4, MinNoOfAt -> 33)))
```

The output come from getJsonKeyValue

```
RedTypP = ^.{14}XY.*$
RedTypC = XY
ExpNoOfAt = 19
AttId = 1
AttNa = Pro Ty
AttMaxLen =1
DataTyName = AN
AttId = 2
AttNa = Pro Cod
AttMaxLen = 6
DataName = AN
AttId = 3
AttNa = REQ CODE
AttMaxLen = 7
DataTyName = AN
RedLen = 117
RedDeIn = 2
MinNoOfAt =19
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Harald My problem is i have function getJsonKeyValue which is basically print the keys and values i'm not able to get any return value from getJsonKeyValue what change i have to do get return value?

Comment: This code, as posted, can't be compiled.  If you have a problem with code that compiles and runs then maybe that's what you should post.

Comment: @jwvh Please see the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in this poorly composed question.  I'll address them in order of severity.

1. `case (k: String, v: Any) => (k + "=" + v)`

This line returns a `String` but the surrounding `foreach()` returns `Unit` so this result string is thrown away. There are two easy solutions for this: 1) use `map` (or some other collection operation) instead of `foreach` in order to collect the result string, or 2) use `println()` to output the result string. `println` returns `Unit`, which matches the `foreach` result.

2. Unaccounted for data type.

Your sample data contains an entry of `String->Map` which your code, and expected output, doesn't account for.

3. Too much poorly formatted sample data.

You've provided more sample data than is needed to produce the desired output and way more than needed to illustrate your issues. (Please read [this page on submitting MCV code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) examples.) It's also presented without the quote marks `"` so those have to be added before it can be used for testing.

With those things in mind, the following compiles with many warnings, but it produces output that appears to match what you're looking for.

```
def getJsonKeyValue(mapIs: Map[String, _]): Unit = {
  mapIs.foreach {
    case (k: String, v: List[Map[String, _]]) => v.foreach(getJsonKeyValue)
    case (k: String, v: Map[String, _])       => getJsonKeyValue(v)
    case (k: String, v)                       => println(k + "=" + v)
  }
}
```

**update**

Here is a version that returns the string representations.

```
def getJsonKeyValue(mapIs: Map[String, _]): Iterable[String] = {
  mapIs.flatMap {
    case (k: String, v: List[Map[String, _]]) => v.flatMap(getJsonKeyValue)
    case (k: String, v: Map[String, _])       => getJsonKeyValue(v)
    case (k: String, v)                       => Iterable(k + "=" + v)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, I don't want to use println in case. what is happening right now if getJsonKeyValue is declaring  any where in main program it prints all values,What is i'm looking for store all the values into getJsonKeyValue function whenever I will write like this println(getJsonKeyValue) then only it will print.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapValues` to apply a function to each value in the map:

```
def getJsonKeyValue(mapIs: Map[String, Any]) :Map[String, Any] = {
  mapIs.mapValues {
    case (v: List[Map[String, Any]]) => v.map(x => getJsonKeyValue(x))
    case (v: Any) => v
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used above set code and getting output like what is my input.Could you see the output what is expecting.